# Which way to test if an element is checked is better? .is(':checked') or .prop('checked')

Tags: jquery, checked

Both `.is(':checked')` and `.prop('checked')` can be used to test if a checkbox is checked.

Are there any interesting/important differences between those two ways of querying the *checked* state or is it pretty much only a matter of personal preference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They both end up checking the same thing.

If you're using 1.6.0 or higher, `prop('checked')` is the most direct jQuery way. jQuery doesn't have to parse and process a selector to figure out what to do.<sup>[Note below]</sup>

You can also (as of 1.6.1) use `attr('checked')` again as with 1.5.x and earlier.

Or you can go directly to the element. Assuming `x` is the thing to be tested, if you *know* that at least one element matched, then:

```
if (x[0].checked) { /* ... */ }
```

If you're not sure and want to hedge your bets:

```
if (x[0] && x[0].checked) { /* ... */ }
```

But unless you're in a *really* tight loop, use whatever you find easiest to read, as the performance differences aren't going to matter. I find the last ones quite easy to read and I know they're very fast, so I use them. But if you find them awkward, use whatever you like best. No harm in using `is(':checked')` if you like it and you're not seeing an actual performance hit from it (which is unlikely barring, again, some kind of tight loop).

---

Note: The *degree* to which `prop` is more direct than `is` varies by browser. `prop` isn't just a direct check of a property, it does go through a couple of levels of indirection first; and `is` isn't necessarily hugely complex: On WebKit browsers, for instance, `is` can be fairly direct as WebKit provides a function to test whether an element matches a selector, and supports `:checked` natively; on Firefox (and, I suspect, IE), `is` results in a *huge* number of function calls as this seemingly-simple selector works its way through the guts of Sizzle.

Comment: .is(':checked') reads better and unless you verify (time + effort) that there are no browser diffs that jQuery is working around then its safer too. Someone did a  pointless article recently that said jquerySet[0].checked was 100 times faster but we are talking super micro optimizations for zero tangible benefit and decrease in readability.

Comment: @mattcodes: Agreed about micro-optimisation and in fact I just added a note about that to the answer. But re your browser diffs point, the `checked` DOM element property is reliable cross-browser, it's one of the ones you can absolutely count on. You're right that there are other things (mostly accessed via `attr`) that are not as reliable.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `prop('checked')` myself (so long as I didn't have to support older jQuery versions) as it is accessing the `checked` property directly of the object and is easy enough to read.

`is(':checked')` runs a bit of extra overhead with string parsing, etc. I generally reserve `:checked` for when *selecting* elements.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is that `.prop('checked')` only determines if the first checkbox in a set is checked, whereas `.is(':checked')` returns true if at least 1 checkbox in a set is checked.

So, if you are trying to determine if any checkboxes in a set are checked, you may consider it easier to use `is(':checked')`.