# elem.is(':checked') vs elem.prop('checked')

Tags: jquery

As title says, whats the difference between `elem.is(':checked')` and `elem.prop('checked')`.

I personally use `elem.is(':checked')` because function `is` explains that I am going to return boolean.

When shall I choose one over the other and why?

Comment: It's aliases. Use the one that fits best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer based on [This SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340294/which-way-to-test-if-an-element-is-checked-is-better-ischecked-or-prop).

If you're using 1.6.0 or higher, prop('checked') is the most direct jQuery way. jQuery doesn't have to parse and process a selector to figure out what to do.

> Note: The degree to which prop is more direct than is varies by
>   browser. prop isn't just a direct check of a property, it does go
>   through a couple of levels of indirection first; and is isn't
>   necessarily hugely complex: On WebKit browsers, for instance, is can
>   be fairly direct as WebKit provides a function to test whether an
>   element matches a selector, and supports :checked natively; on Firefox
>   (and, I suspect, IE), is results in a huge number of function calls as
>   this seemingly-simple selector works its way through the guts of
>   Sizzle.

Test Result : 
[jQuery prop('checked') vs. is(':checked')](https://jsperf.com/prop-vs-ischecked/96)

Answer (score 1):

> [.prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) is used to get/set the element's property value. While
>   passing one argument, it will return the property (first argument)
>   value and while passing two arguments, it will set the second argument
>   as value to the first argument (element's property).

Hence, `elem.prop('checked')` will return the value of the `checked` property. The data type of the value can be anything (boolean/string) based on the property.

If you check `elem.prop('type')`, this will return the value of the `type` property which is a `string` data type and will return `checkbox` as output.

> [.is](http://api.jquery.com/is/) is used to check whether the element is matching the
>   condition passed in the argument is true/false. Hence, the data type
>   will be always boolean (true/false).

Hence, you can check whether the element is checked (or) not using `elem.is(':checked')`. Here, `:checked` is called as `pseudo` element to check the `state` of the element (checked/not checked).

You can also check whether the element is a checkbox or not using `elem.is('[type="checkbox"]')`. Here `[type="checkbox"]` is used to check the property `type` of the element is whether `checkbox` or not.